# Best way to convert string representation of hex to byte? (Working with Arduino)

Tags: c, string, arduino, byte

I'm sending in a hex representation of a byte through the serial port and I needed to convert it to a byte to use in my application. I've approached it several different ways and it looks like there's got to be an easier way to approach it than the way I have been (and I haven't yet found anything online that resolves this issue). I'm guessing there's probably a simple function that does what I want it to do without 3 or 4 different conversions.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to approach this?

Essentially, I'm trying to take a string (inString) with value "CE" and store the equivalent in byte form (0xCE or 206) into outByte. Below is what I'm currently working with:

Original Code:

```
String inString = “CE”
Byte outByte;
outByte = inString.toInt();
printData("outByte: " + String(outByte),serialchan);
```

Output:

```
outByte: 0
```

Additional approaches:

```
String inString = “CE”
Byte outByte;

char tempchar[2];
String tempstring;
inString.toCharArray(tempchar, 4); // Works with 4, not with 2 for whatever reason
printData("inString: " + String(inString),serialchan);
printData("inString hex: " + String(tempchar),serialchan);

tempstring = "0x" + String(inString);
printData("inString in string hex: " + String(tempstring),serialchan);
outByte = (byte)tempstring.toInt();
printData("outByte: " + String(outByte),serialchan);
```

Output:

```
outByte: 0                                                        
inString: CE                                                   
inString hex: CE                                                
inString in string hex: 0xCE                                     
outByte: 0
```

I'm expecting outByte to read 206 (I'll convert it to a hex string later, I'm guessing that's pretty straight forward). Like I said, I think I'm close . . . but there just seems like there should be a simple one or two line solution to this. If you have any suggestions, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't look like C at all.

Comment: You can convert a C string in various number bases to an integer using `strtol`. For example `long val = strtol(inString, NULL, 16);`. Or you can use `sscanf`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I actually tried that but had issues when passing it a variable.  I can hardcode it and it seems to work ok, but when I try to run it like you have above, I get the following:

error: cannot convert 'String' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'long int strtol(const char*, char**, int)'
 long val = strtol(inString, NULL, 16);
                                     ^
exit status 1
cannot convert 'String' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'long int strtol(const char*, char**, int)'

Comment: You could copy the Arduino `String` to a C-style buffer first with its `getBytes()` method?

Comment: @WeatherVane Yeah, I've tried a few things like this and it ends up returning ASCII values instead.  I tried: byte outByteArray[2];
inString.getBytes(outByteArray,4);
printData("outByte[0]: " + String(outByteArray[0]),serialchan);
printData("outByte[1]: " + String(outByteArray[1]),serialchan); and can get outByte[0] to be 67 and outByte[1] to be 69.  I can probably index the stupid thing but I'm blown away by how difficult it is to do simple things in arduino . . .

Comment: Don't use such tiny strings. The one you supplied is too small, and you told the function it is twice is actual size.

Comment: @WeatherVane I kind of need to . . . the string I'm converting it a byte (two chars).  You'd think this would be pretty straight forward but there are so many functions that require sending it a const and won't allow you to send a variable . . .

Comment: Sorry, C strings have a nul terminator, 2 bytes is too short. Use a buffer size `4` and pass the *actual size of the buffer available*. If it is length `4` then you pass `4` to the `getBytes`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Ah, that makes sense.  I actually had done that above (noticed 2 didn't work, went to 4) and assumed it was because of something like that.  At least that confirms why!  I originally thought you meant I needed to have more than one byte in the string.  I ended up just writing a large convoluted function to handle it but it looks like it worked.  Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind about validation (i.e. input string is always valid hexadecimal ASCII string) you can use this case-insensitive almost branchless snippet:

```c
static unsigned char nibble(char c)
{
    return c % 16 + 9*(c >> 6);
}

unsigned int hex2num(const char *s)
{
    unsigned int r = 0;
    while (*s)
        r = (r << 4) | nibble(*s++);
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int convertDigit(char a) {
    if (a >= '0' && a <= '9') return a - '0';
    if (a >= 'A' && a <= 'F') return a + 10 - 'A';
    assert(0 && "not valid");
}

int HexToByte(char *string) {
    unsigned int length = strlen(string);
    int value = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        value += convert(string[i]) * pow(16, length - i - 1);
    }
    return value;
}
```

I wrote this relay fast but should do what you need. Pay attention that require math for the pow function but that can be easily implemented.

[EDIT] thanks to @dimich

```
int convertDigit(char a) {
    if (a >= '0' && a <= '9') return a - '0';
    if (a >= 'A' && a <= 'F') return a + 10 - 'A';
    assert(0 && "not valid");
}

int HexToByte(char *str) {
    int value = 0;
    while (*str) value = (value << 4) | convert(*str++);
    return value;
}
```

Comment: I essentially ended up writing something along these lines based on an example I saw.  I would've thought there would be an easier way to approach it but I checked everywhere, no luck.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: `while (*str) value = (value << 4) | convert(*str++)`. No "pow function" needed.